# Haskell - Function that splits up a [char] into a String

Tags: haskell

I want a function that can turn an array into a string while inputting some new lines in there too.

Essentially let's say I have the list: [1234567890]
I would like to pass that in with an integer and return that list as a String that is formatted like such:

(if the Int was 5, it would be)

```
"12345"
"67890"
```

I'm thinking I can do something like:

```
split :: Int -> [char] -> String
split n (x:xs) = split (take n-1 (x:xs)) -- I'm trying to make this recursive
```

I'm also going to assume that whatever length the array is will be divisible by the Int I pass in.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. List of `Char` is already `String` (that's how `String` is literally defined), but your output example shows two strings, not one.

Comment: I would essentially just like to format the list. If there's a way to output 2 strings that'd be great, I was also thinking trying to push a \n char at the end of the length defined above.

Comment: I can't understand what is the intended output type: if you want to return exactly two strings, use `.... -> (String, String)`. If you want to return many, use `... -> [String]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you have to make `split` recursive, but in your recursive step it did not receive the same number of parameters, and you tried to pass parts of the argument. The `n` can stay the same for every step, and when you `take n`  out of the list in each step you also have to drop these `n` elements for the remaining steps.

```
splitN _ [] = ""
splitN n l = (take n l) ++ "\n" ++ (splitN n $ drop n l)
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OP's type signature

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Right, just saw that after your comment on the question.

Comment: Alright, thanks I appreciate the comment! My output is looking like "12345\n67890" though. Do you have any additional ideas? The top of the split function looks like split :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]

Comment: It looks like that because ghci just displays the \n character like that. You see that when you really print the output, formatted, e.g. ```putStrLn (splitN 5 "1234567890")```. Now it really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Ah, yes thank you @donttrythat I really appreciate your help!